# The boolean value of the objects coming from a Query is wrong

Tags: mysql

I have this activity_company table which includes an activity and company. I am trying to order the result of this query by modified_date and id. And in the activity table there is a boolean field such as shared. All the shared values are false in the database but after this query the resulted objects' shared fields are displayed as true even if they are still false in the DB. Any idea what causes this situation ?

```
SELECT activity.*
FROM activity
INNER JOIN activity_company ON activity.id=activity_company.activity_id
WHERE  activity_company.company_id=1
ORDER BY activity.modified_date, activity.id
```

This is the activity class;

```
@Entity
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String param;
    private Date createdDate;
    private int activityType;

    private long classNameId;
    private long classPK;

    private Date modifiedDate;
    private boolean shared;

    @ManyToOne
    private User creatorUser;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company creatorCompany;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity")
    private List<ActivityCompany> activityCompanies = new ArrayList<ActivityCompany>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity")
    private List<ActivityAttachment> activityAttachments;

    public Activity(String param, User user, int activityType) {
        this.param = param;
        this.createdDate = new Date();
        this.activityType = activityType;
        this.creatorUser = user;
        this.modifiedDate = new Date();
    }
```

and activitycompany;

```
@Entity
public class ActivityCompany {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Activity activity;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;

    public Activity getActivity() {

        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {

        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {

        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {

        this.company = company;
    }


    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

}
```

Comment: The amount of information you provided is rather insufficient. You didn't even show where the `shared` field is pulled from the database, leaving it up to us to assume is't part of `activity.*`. Try simplifying your query to pull only one field that yields incorrect values, and trace its path through your system to see where `0` becomes a `true`.

Comment: MySQL won't send a true where there is a false. It sounds like it's somewhere in your code that evaluates the field incorrectly. Post the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: I wrote this query directly database and in the given result this boolean fields value is coming wrong. I dont think it is related to my code.